# how to filter data in XML using child in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ipad, filter

i have an xml data like

```
 <MenuItem><ItemId>0e29531a-c08f-49a9-a8d0-9cdbeb156145</ItemId><ItemName>Grades</ItemName><MenuItemId>4dc25103-906c-44e7-ae94-a30c37c8c5e6</MenuItemId></MenuItem>

<MenuItem><ItemId>72a10662-c1e2-42bf-b8d9-0a879b729e54</ItemId><ItemName>Manage Account(s)</ItemName><MenuItemId>b0d16a5d-9468-40a3-879c-006c8583ddba</MenuItemId></MenuItem>

<MenuItem><ItemId>49155938-346d-44c9-b44d-70c2770b7414</ItemId><ItemName>Linked Guardians</ItemName><ParentId>72a10662-c1e2-42bf-b8d9-0a879b729e54</ParentId></MenuItem>
```

so i want to fetch `ItemName` of only first two tags, but not last tag, because last tag is child of tag 2, but it  has  `itemName`too, the order of this xml lines may change.

how to fetch this in objective C

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ItemName"]){

            xmlStringFileObject.xmltitle=nodecontent;
        }
    }
```

i tried the above, but i am getting all the three

Comment: I am not sure any xml parser will do this, but you can store in dictionary and do all range of manipulation to find what you need.

Comment: how can we manipulate in dictionary

Comment: Wherever you have a key "parentID" dont use them.

Comment: yes, you must add the element in a mutable dictionary at the end of that method inside the if

Comment: it terminates :count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'